# Search in a string using Regular Expressions Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I'm new to jquery and I am making a project. I already searched in the internet and checked some other things in stackoverflow but I haven't seen something that match what I need.

So I have a Postcode Inclusion field which can have one or more postcodes.
Ex. `CC,DD,AA` or `CC` if it is only one. and from those input I need to
compare in a string variable that has the all the postcode inclusions.
Ex. `var postcodes_include = "CC,AA,DD,KK,BB";` and the input field, if the user has type only `AA,BB` it will search through `postcodes_include` and will find if it match something.

Thanks!

Comment: does `postcodes_include` have to be a string? May it be an array of strings?

Comment: postcodes_include is string, it is from the database.

Answer (score 1):

First split `postcode_incluedes` into an array. The split up the input, loop over them, and test whether they're in the array. No regex required.

```
function validate_postcodes(postcodes_include) {
    var postcodes_include_array = postcodes_include.split(',');
    var postcodes = $("#postcodes").val().split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(postcodes[i], postcodes_include_array == -1) {
            alert("Postcode " + postcodes[i] + " is not allowed");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex required for this answer. You can use string .split() and .search() to achieve what you want like this:

```
var postcodes_include = "CC,AA,DD,KK,BB"
var known_postcodes = []
var unknown_postcodes = []

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault()
        // split the input to get all codes
        var inputSplit = $('input').val().split(",")
        // iterate all the input codes
        for(c in inputSplit){
            var code = inputSplit[c]
            if(postcodes_include.search(code) >= 0){
                known_postcodes.push(code)
            }else{
                unknown_postcodes.push(code)
            }
        }
        alert(known_postcodes);
        alert(unknown_postcodes);
    })
})
```

[HERE a workin fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ff3h8qgt/)